# Tkinter app using sockets hangs on start

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

I am having problems with a socket/tkinter login app. The server is on a Raspberry Pi but even with the server not on I see no reason that this should hang on startup. I have imported a module I have made which I will include.

Why does it hang?

Here is my client code - the one that hangs:

```
import socket, pickle
import Tkinter as tk
import loginutility

class Server(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = socket.socket()
        self.p = 10000
        self.ip = "192.168.1.120"
    def addUser(self, userinfo):
        puserinfo = pickle.dumps(userinfo)
        self.s.connect((self.ip, self.p))
        self.s.sendall("check")
        self.sendall(puserinfo)
        if self.s.recv(1024) == False:
            self.s.sendall("add")
            self.send(puserinfo)
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def userDump(self):
        self.s.sendall("userdump")
        return pickle.loads(self.s.recv(1024))
class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

class LoginFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        self.l = loginutility.LoginBox(self)
        login = tk.Button(self, text="Login", command=self.login)
        login.pack()
    def login(self):
        u, p = self.l.values()
        users = Server.userDump()
        if u in users and users[u] == p:
            tk.Label(self, text="Success").pack()

main = Main()
mf = LoginFrame(main)
main.mainloop()
```

The server code - wasn't on when tested:

```
import loginutility as lu
import socket
import pickle
s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
address = ''
port = 10000
s.bind((address, port))
s.listen(5)

users = lu.UserList("accounts")
while True:
        c, clientaddress = s.accept()
        c.send("You're Connected")
        d = c.recv(1024)
        if d == "add":
                userdata = c.recv(1024)
                username, password = pickle.loads(userdata)
                users.adduser(username, password)
                print "User {} added with password of {}.".format(username, password)
                c.send("Success")
        elif d == "check":
                username, password = pickle.loads(c.recv(1024))
                if users.checkuser(username) == False:
                        c.sendall(False)
                else:
                        c.sendall(True)
        elif d == "userdump":
                c.send(pickle.dumps(users.dumpuser())

        c.close()
```

Necessary loginutility code:

```
class LoginBox:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.l1=Label(parent, text="Username:").grid()
        self.ubox=Entry(parent)
        self.ubox.grid()
        self.l2=Label(parent, text="Password:").grid()
        self.pbox=Entry(parent, show="*")
        self.pbox.grid()
    def values(self):
        return (self.ubox.get(), self.pbox.get())

class UserList:
    def __init__(self, file=None):
        self.users = {}
        self.file = file
        if file != None:
            with open(file, "rb") as f:
                self.users = pickle.load(f)
    def adduser(self, user, pswrd):
        self.users[user] = pswrd
        if file != None:
            with open(self.file, "wb") as f:
                pickle.dump(self.users, f)
    def dumpuser(self):
        return self.users
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: if the server code wasn't on when this code was tested, why include it? You should reduce this code down to the absolute fewest lines that still reproduce the problem.  In this case you can probably remove 2/3 of the code.

Comment: Is your server running when you tested. It's possible that when you call self.s.connect() your app wait  forever your server response. If your server is not running the client will freeze there. You can solve this by adding a [timeout](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) to your socket and you can also avoid locking your app by doing network stuff in another thread. But watchout, because threading is going to make you application **much** more complex to debug.

Comment: @TomásGonzalezDowling No it isn't that, I have accepted the answer below ⬇️ but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it hangs is because you are mixing both `pack` and `grid` in the same parent widget. Consider the following code:

```
class LoginFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        self.l = loginutility.LoginBox(self)
        login = tk.Button(self, text="Login", command=self.login)
        login.pack()
```

In the above code, you create a frame (`self`), create a `LoginBox` that is a child of `self`, and a button that is also the child of `self`. The button uses `pack`, and `LoginBox.__init__` uses `grid`.

You cannot use both `pack` and `grid` on widgets that share a common parent. In this case the common parent is the instance of `LoginFrame`.